# Location of CoreMedia framework

Tags: ios

I've been attempting to dive into mediaserverd which runs on iOS.  Pulling the binary and running `otool -L` on it reveals, unsurprisingly, that it's linked against `/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia`.  However, that directory on the phone doesn't have any file called `CoreMedia`.  In fact, all it has are two `.plist` files and some text file called `CodeResources`.

Where is the actual Mach-O file for the CoreMedia framework?

Comment: Welcome to RE.SE. An iOS/MacOS "framework" is a directory. Code objects are expected to be found in a subdirectory named `contents/macOS` under the `.framework` directory (the parent of the one you are in)